# Get the maximum value of all columns 1-3 with common column 4

Tags: linux, awk, sort, uniq

Given an input txt file:

```
$ cat input.txt
-1 23 34 cheese
34 20 15 cheese
-4 -4 20 tomato
13 -3 14 tomato
4  6   7 tomato
-3 -3 -3 potato
```

I can uniqify the data based on column 4, retaining the record with maximum value in column 1 using:

```
$ cat input.txt | sort -k4 -k1,1rn | uniq -f3
```

Which gives:

```
34 20 15 cheese
13 -3 14 tomato
-3 -3 -3 potato
```

I however want to uniqify the data on column 4 and retain the maximum value in all records with the same column 4. Something like:

```
34 23 34 cheese
13 6 20 tomato
-3 -3 -3 potato
```

Any quick way to achieve this?

Comment: Do you have access to [GNU datamash](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/)?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using AWK:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
!keys[$4] { keys[$4] = 1; for (i = 1; i < 4; i++) max[$4][i] = $i }
{ for (i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
    if (max[$4][i] < $i) max[$4][i] = $i
} }
END { for (key in max) print max[key][1], max[key][2], max[key][3], key }
```

This tracks the three maximum values for each key in column four.

There is one caveat: the order of keys isn't maintained.

Comment: This solves caveat 1 I guess:

#!/usr/bin/awk -f
!keys[$4] { 
    keys[$4] = 1
    for (i = 1; i < 4; i++) {max[$4,i] = $i }
}
{ 
    for (i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
        if (max[$4,i] < $i) max[$4,i] = $i
    } 
}
END { for (key in keys) print max[key,1], max[key,2], max[key,3], key }

Comment: It does indeed, I’ll edit my answer. The point of initialising the array the first time round is so that negative values are handled correctly; a missing value is interpreted as 0.